# Android Studio не видит класса из библиотеки, что я подключил

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin

Такая проблема я нашел библиотеку WheelPicker поставил по инструкции grudle файл модулей проекта

`implementation 'com.github.open-android:WheelPicker:v1.0.0'`

Вот эту строку

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
```

в grudle файл проекта не добавлял, потому что у меня там вот это

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.3.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.3.1' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.7.20' apply false
}
```

Впрочем все собралось. Но класс не находит вот с такой строкой

```
<com.itheima.wheelpicker.WheelPicker
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:wheel_atmospheric="true"
                app:wheel_curved="true"
                app:wheel_cyclic="true"
                app:wheel_selected_item_position="5"
                app:wheel_item_text_color="#66ff0000"
                app:wheel_selected_item_text_color="#6600ffff"/>
```

пишет ошибку:

```
Missing classes
The following classes could not be found:
- com.itheima.wheelpicker.WheelPicker
```

Answer (score 1):

Надо было строчку с maven { url "https://jitpack.io" } действительно добавить, но не туда куда написано, сейчас видимо что то поменялось надо добавлять в settings.grudle
Странно почему это тогда собиралось.

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
rootProject.name = "Predictor"
include ':app'
```